# bootstrap 4 modal not showing after button is clicked with VueJs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I just learned vuejs with bootstrap 4 and I tried to display modal provided that when the create button was not clicked then the HTML modal tag is not displayed in the inspect element, and after the create button click bootstrap modal displayed. When the button create first time click HTML modal tag display on inspect element but bootstrap modal cannot be displayed on the browser page and the second time the bootstrap modal can be displayed. Here is the source code that I made with Laravel, can you help me on this issue, thank you.

> **User.vue**

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="card-deck mb-3">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <div class="card-header bg-success text-white">
                            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-bold">
                                <!-- Button create user -->
                                <button @click="initAddUser()" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create New User</button>
                                <span class="float-right">User</span>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">

                            <!-- Bootstrap modal -->
                            <div v-if="showModal" class="modal fade" id="add_user_model" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="add_user_model_label" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header bg-info text-white">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="add_user_model_label"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New User</h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <!-- Message errors create user -->
                                            <div class="alert alert-danger" v-if="errors.length > 0">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                                <h5>{{ messages }}</h5>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="font-weight-bold" for="name">Name :</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" v-model="user.name">
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="font-weight-bold" for="name">Email :</label>
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" v-model="user.email">
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="font-weight-bold" for="password">Password:</label>
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" v-model="user.password">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" @click="createUser()">Submit</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Js**

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                user: {
                    name: '',
                    email: '',
                    password: ''
                },
                errors: [],
                users: [],
                showModal: false,

            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.readUsers();
        },
        methods: {
            initAddUser() {
                this.errors = [];
                $("#add_user_model").modal("show");
                this.showModal = true;
            },
            reset() {
                this.user.name = '';
                this.user.email = '';
                this.user.password = '';
            },
            readUsers() {
                axios.get('/user/show')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.users = response.data.users;
                    });
            },
            createUser() {
                axios.post('/user', {
                        name: this.user.name,
                        email: this.user.email,
                        password: this.user.password,
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        this.reset();
                        this.users.push(response.data.user);
                        this.readUsers();
                        $("#add_user_model").modal("hide");
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        this.errors = [];
                        this.messages = error.response.data.message;

                        if (error.response.data.errors.name) {
                            this.errors.push(error.response.data.errors.name[0]);
                        }

                        if (error.response.data.errors.email) {
                            this.errors.push(error.response.data.errors.email[0]);
                        }

                        if (error.response.data.errors.password) {
                            this.errors.push(error.response.data.errors.password[0]);
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

> **Result images inspect element**

1. This image button first time click https://ibb.co/jKENbU
2. This image button second time click https://ibb.co/nRy4qp

Comment: change order of these lines 
 this.showModal = true;
 $("#add_user_model").modal("show");

Comment: I have tried to change the order and the results remain the same, maybe any other way ?